# astropy.io.ascii.write string to file without quotes

Tags: python, ascii, astropy

I am trying to write a string and a float into a file using:

```
t=['SDSS J2000']
data=[10] 
astropy.io.ascii.write([t,data] ,'data.dat',names=['name','num'],formats={'name':'%s','num':'%f'})
```

the output file is:

```
name num
"SDSS J2000" 10.000000
```

how can I write the string to file without the quotes, like this:

```
SDSS J2000 10.000000
```

Comment: Looks like you need 3 columns instead of 2. Space is used as a delimiter, so that's why a string containing a space needs quoting.

Comment: it's not the only difference: looks that you want to drop the title as well right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided 2 data and 2 values, so `astropy` quotes the data to be able to read it back.

Do you *really* need `astropy` for this? Standard python does it easily using `str.format`:

```
t=['SDSS J2000']
data=[10]
with open("data.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("{} {} {:f}".format(*(t[0].split()+data)))
```

if you *really* want to achieve that using `astropy` you can use `quotechar` set to space (and use the option to avoid displaying header):

```
astropy.io.ascii.write([t,data] ,'data.dat',names=['name','num'],format='no_header',quotechar=' ',formats={'name':'%s','num':'%f'})
```

this writes:

```
  SDSS  J2000  10.000000
```

so too many spaces, expected when you try to twist the library's arm into writing data that cannot be read back reliably

EDIT: another way to do it is to let `astropy` write its quotes and remove them afterwards, using `io.StringIO` to avoid writing/reading/writing to disk:

```
import astropy.io.ascii
import io

t=['SDSS J2000']
data=[10]
buf=io.StringIO()
astropy.io.ascii.write([t,data] ,buf,names=['name','num'],format='no_header',formats={'name':'%s','num':'%f'})
with open("data.dat") as f:
    f.write(buf.getvalue().replace('"',""))
```

file now contains:

```
SDSS J2000 10.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `split` with `space` as delimiter and you `split` one more time with `"` as delimiter.

For example (I don't try it) :

```
first = str.split(string, delimiter=' ')
```

if you display the result : `print first[0]` gives `"SDSS`

Then :

```
second_1 = str.split(first[0], delimiter = '"')
second_2 = str.split(first[1], delimiter = '"')
```

you will obtain SDSS with `second_1[1]`

Then you return :

```
print second_1[1] + second_2[0] + first[2]
```

will give : `SDSS J2000 10.0000`

[image]

As I said, It's an example, I didn't try it ! But the logic is there.
**I think it exists a really better answer than mine, but it's a way to do that**

Comment: Thanks for your answer with detailed description. That‘s awesome!(*^__^*)